# maintain password value after failed login attempt

Tags: forms, users

I'm working on a custom login page for users. I have some special elements on the page, which might cause authentication to fail even though a user enters a valid username and password combination.

After a failed authentication attempt, the username field still keeps the username they entered, but the password field is blank. I would like the password field to keep its value, like the username field does.

I'm starting the form with `user_login()`. I added a check to add in the password:

```
if (isset($form_state['input']['pass']) ) {
// user has submitted the login form once.

 // maintain their entered password
  $form['pass']['#default_value'] = $form_state['input']['pass'];
}
```

Yet it doesn't survive.

How can I re-populate the password field after a failed login?

Comment: Where did you add that code? Can you provide more context, and code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [password field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#password) doesn't use the "#default_value" property. This means that is not possible to pre fill the field with a default value as it is possible with a [textfield field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#textfield). As it is not possible to set a default value for the field, a password field is always shown empty.

It is what I would expect, especially when a validation handler returns an error for the entered password. If the password is wrong, I don't see any reason to pre fill the field with what previously entered, considering that what the user sees is something similar to "•••••" (or a group of asterisks).

Comment: It would just be nice for a user not to have to enter their password again because they forgot to check a box on another part of the page. ( I didn't create the requirements for this site :)

Comment: I understood that, but still when an error is reported from the validation handler for a password, the error is usually "The password is wrong." If a module, for example, wants to avoid a user uses the same password for more than X times, it should not return a validation error when the password has been used X+1 times; it should allow the user to log in, and then force the user to change the password.

Comment: Makes sense -- I wasn't thinking about that.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it should be:

```
$form_state['values']['pass']
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything goes, even though [#default_value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#default_value) is really not supported for the [password](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#password) element.

To make it work you'll have to override the default `<input type="password">` theming. Then, use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to pass the value from `$form_state` back to `$form`.

I got it to work on my side with code like this:

```
sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/template.php:

function YOUR_THEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'password' => array(
      'variables' => array('element' => NULL)
    )
  );
}

function YOUR_THEME_password($element) {
  $size = $element['#size'] ? ' size="'. $element['#size'] .'" ' : '';
  $maxlength = $element['#maxlength'] ? ' maxlength="'. $element['#maxlength'] .'" ' : '';
  $default_value = $element['#default_value'] ? ' value="'. $element['#default_value'] .'" ' : '';

  _form_set_class($element, array('form-text'));
  $output = '<input type="password" name="'. $element['#name'] .'" id="'. $element['#id'] .'" '. $default_value . $maxlength . $size . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) .' />';
  return theme('form_element', $element, $output);
}

sites/all/modules/YOUR_MODULE/YOUR_MODULE.module:

function YOUR_MODULE_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['pass']['#default_value'] = $form_state['post']['pass'];
}
```

Now I'm not quite sure about the last one, though. I was expecting `$form_state['values']` like IMO suggested, but I only have `$form_state['post']`. While that works, somebody may want to clarify.